# cudaMemcpy affects other variables

Tags: pointers, memory, cuda, copy, device

Here's my code for a program that does a histogram on an image then a prefix sum scan on the histogram http://codepad.org/4RMtWn1e. The problem is at line 396, which correctly outputs the value of numBins (number of bins for histogram) at 1024. I than copy the histogram from device memory back to host memory. This somehow changes the value of numBins and the next output of that is 0. That seems very strange. I didn't make any specific modifications to numBins, but it changes the value anyway. I feel like if I can figure this out, It will me understand why my program isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
unsigned int* h_histogram;
h_histogram = (unsigned int*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned int)* 1024);

std::cout << numBins;

checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(&h_histogram, d_histogram, sizeof(unsigned int)* numBins, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
                           ^
                           |
                            h_histogram is already a pointer
```

Instead do this:

```
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(h_histogram, d_histogram, sizeof(unsigned int)* numBins, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
```

(the only change being to remove the ampersand in front of `h_histogram`

I'm not sure really why `numBins` got corrupted exactly, but this particular errant `cudaMemcpy` operation would not be copying to the destination you expect, instead it would overwrite the pointer value stored at `h_histogram` as well as anything that came after it.  And if `numBins` happened to be stored after it, it would overwrite that also.